# Error al insertar datos en vista MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy intentando guardar datos en una vista pero me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Can not modify more than one base table through a join view 'bd_calidad.vista_novedades_plantilla'
```

La instruccion que estoy ejecutando es la siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO `bd_calidad`.`vista_novedades_plantilla` (
`plantilla` ,
`codigoNovedad` ,
`categoria` ,
`categoriaNombre` ,
`categoriaDescripcion` ,
`novedadNombre` ,
`novedadDescripcion` ,
`puntos` ,
`orden`
)
VALUES (
'7','1', '1','PROTOCOLO','PROTOCOLO', 'SALUDO','SALUDO', '0', '1'
)
```

he buscado en internet mi problema pero aún no encuentro solucion espero me ayuden

Comment: Mira que estés colocando bien el nombre de la base de datos, de igual manera sí estás dentro de la base de datos ejecutando la sql no debería ser necesario hacer eso

Comment: si estoy en la base de datos pero me bota es error al insertar y no sé a qué se refiere osea qué estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Estás desde phpmyadmin?

Comment: si estoy ejecutando desde ahi el query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vista es una tabla virtual (es decir que no existe) que es definida por una consulta, por lo tanto non puedes hacer el insert. [Más info](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15).

Por lo tanto debes saber como esta creada dicha vista por ejemplo supongamos es solo un **join** en dos tablas: **TablaA** y **TablaB** pero solo tomamos el atributo **attrA1** de la **TablaA** y **attrB2** de la **TablaB**

Tendriamos la siguiente query:

```sql
CREATE VIEW test
AS
Select t1.attrA1, t2.attrB2
From TablaA as t1
inner join TablaB as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Como podrás observar para que tu insert se despliegue en la vista tendrás que insertar datos en ambas tablas y que estos coincidan en el **id** para que la vista los muestre al hacer un select de la vista.